# How to use the chain rule in the black hole thermodynamics considering $S$, $P$, and $Q$?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes

To study the first law of thermodynamics in a special case I faced a problem related to the chain rule. Suppose a Smarr formula whith the general form  $M=M(S,P,Q)$. Now, considering the entropy $S=S(r_h, Q)$, the electric charge $Q$, and pressure (related to the cosmological constant) $P=P(r_h,Q)$, how can I use the chain rule to determine $T=(\frac{\partial M}{\partial S})_{Q,P}$, $U=(\frac{\partial M}{\partial Q})_{S,P}$, and $V=(\frac{\partial M}{\partial P})_{S,Q}$?

P.S. $r_h$ is the horizon radius and $Q$ is the electric charge here.

Comment: Dear @Noone any idea? :)

Comment: You want to determine these derivatives in terms of what variables? You already have them in terms of $S$ $Q$, $P$.